# Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory)

Tags: android, admob, android-manifest, androidx

I want to add google admob to my app but after adding their dependency
`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.0.0'` the app could no longer compile or run it just shows this error

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
>       is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-37:19 to override.

Comment: it's due to using both androidX libraries and support libraries. You can't use both, you have to select one and then stick to it.

Comment: how can i switch

Comment: if you want to move towards androidX then open Refactor from top menu and click on Migrate to AndroidX which will be the second last option on the drop down. If you want to stick to support libraries then you have to remove androidX dependencies from your gradle file and import the normal ones.

Comment: how can i get admob normal dependency

Comment: this is the normal dependency for admob = 'implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.0.0''

Comment: migrate option is not in my android studio refactor options

Comment: which version of android studio you are using ?

Comment: android studio 3.1.4

Comment: then you have to do it manually which is a tiring task. I would suggest you to stick to support libraries instead for the time being.

Comment: yes i will just use firebase dependencies instead. it should work right?

Comment: yeah it should work.

Comment: @Umair i will go with that then. thank you for your time